# Convergence of the Roothaan-Hall equations

Tags: convergence, hartree-fock

Suppose that we are given a time-independent quantum mechanical system whose wavefunction depends on three space coordinates. Let $F$ be the Fock operator of the system. Suppose also that we have a set of functions $f_k : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{C}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $$\mathrm{clos} \;\mathrm{span} \{f_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\} = L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) .$$ Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $B_n = \{ f_k : k = 0,\ldots,n\}$. Let $$F_n C_n  = E_n S_n C_n$$ be the Roothaan-Hall equations of the system in basis set $B_n$. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the solutions of the Roothaan-Hall equations to converge to the exact solutions of the Hartree-Fock equations of the system when $n \to \infty$? Does $\{ f_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ have to be a Riesz basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$? We may consider only the ground state of the system.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but [*Int. J. Quantum Chem.* **2000,** *79* (2), 82–90](https://doi.org/10.1002/1097-461X(2000)79:2%3C82::AID-QUA3%3E3.0.CO;2-I) looked at the convergence of the traditional Roothaan approach and proved that it can only converge to a stationary point or bounce between two points which are not solutions to the HF equations.